# Issue Getting windows client display name in an .asmx service script in (VB) ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, userprincipal

I'm very new to ASP.NET and I've been struggling trying to get the username of the client sending requests to a web service script on the server side.

After searching online I found two properties that supposedly gives the server page access to the client username;
[User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) 
and then I got another piece of code from an ex-senior colleague who left before figuring this problem out, his function used UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName

and for both of these I'm getting a blank string.

I've searched for what my problem could be and I'm suspecting it's because I don't authenticate the user on the server side somehow.
I just accessed those two properties/variables directly (UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName and User.Identity.Name)

can anyone help shed some light on this issue please? I haven't a clue what I'm doing wrong/ not doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct; you have to explicitly authenticate the user via a built-in .NET mechanism such as Forms Authentication or Windows Authentication for `User.Identity` to be populated by the framework.

You didn't specify from where the requests are coming (web, windows app, windows service, etc), but [this article](http://www.bipinjoshi.net/articles/dbd724e9-78f0-4a05-adfb-190d151103b2.aspx) provides nice overview of getting Forms Authentication set up with asmx.